# Specific format for Mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get specific format output after grouping data in a collection.

The data in the collection looks like this:

```
[
{
  "country": "UK",
  "business": "computer",
  "companies": 24
},
{
  "country": "UK",
  "business": "automotive",
  "companies": 12
},
{
  "country": "US",
  "business": "medical",
  "companies": 3
},
{
  "country": "US",
  "business": "food",
  "companies": 53
}
]
```

I've used the following aggregation to group `business` based on the `country`:

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$country",
      business: {
        $addToSet: "$business"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And I'm getting the following result:

```
[
{
  "_id": "UK",
  "business": [ "computer", "automotive" ]
},
{
  "_id": "US",
  "business": [ "food", "medical" ]
}
]
```

My question: How can I use the pipelines and format the output into something like the following?

```
[
   {
      "US": {
         "business":[ "food", "medical" ]
      }
   },
   {
      "UK": {
         "business":[ "computer", "automotive" ]
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `$arrayToObject`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$country", business: {$addToSet: "$business"}}},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      res: [{k: "$_id", v: {business: "$business"}}]
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$res"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kRs-BN9kABi)